# How do I compile my .scss file into multiple .css files depending on the variables

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I have a simple gulp build to compile my .scss files:

gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/assets/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
});

...
```

index.scss:

```
$brand-primary: #b0b0b0;
// $brand-primary: #b1b1b1;
// $brand-primary: #b2b2b2;

...
```

In index.scss I have multiple versions of the `$brand-primary` variable I want the file to compile with, e.g. I want gulpfile.js to automatically create multiple versions of index.scss depending on the `$brand-primary` variable: index-1.css, index-2.css, index-3.css, etc. with the `$brand-primary` value equal to `#b0b0b0` first, then `#b1b1b1`, then `#b2b2b2` accordingly.

The idea is to create multiple color options for my template without manually recompiling it for each color.

PS: I am aware of CSS variables, however those won't work with color function like `darken($brand-primary, 10%);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be very hard to do what you ask purely programatically. I'm not even sure it's possible.

Why don't you just create 3 index.scss files each with different $brand-color and and then import everything else in them. Or even better make another file which will import all of your other *.scss files and then just import that file and color in each index file. So your index files would look like this:

```
$brand-primary: #b0b0b0;

@import 'style';
```

and _style.scss would have all of your other scss dependencies.